# Engine stalls when RPMs reach 4500 under load, but not when vehicle stationary

Tags: bmw, stall

I have a 2006 BMW 325ci.  There are 2 faults, one is life threatening.
1) Driving on freeway if I attempt to pass and engine reaches 4500 rpm it suddenly stalls, and I coast to the side and survive one more time.  If I am stationary in my yard it will not stall at 4500 rpm.  I get error codes of P0171 and P0174 (lean bank 1 and bank 2).  I cleaned MAF and changed fuel filter, but no change.  I found no air leak using propane gas blow torch as leak detector.
2)  Second problem (maybe related).  Engine idles and runs very rough on cool mornings, the cooler the rougher.  After warming the engine 1 minute, it runs and idles fine the rest of the day. From this I get error codes P0303, P0304, and P0306 (cyl 3, 4, and 6 missfire).

Please help before the engine stall kills me on the interslam.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like fuel pressure drops off, fuel pump is weak, you would need a fuel pressure gauge connected when it stalls to check this